# Does view.remove remove it from the memory?

Tags: android

I am wondering if `parent.removeView(child)` actually removes child from the memory.

Or is it just the linkage between the parent and the child that is removed?

If the latter is correct, is there any way to remove the child view for the sake of memory allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent.removeView(child)` actually removes the `View` from the View hierarchy, in other words removing the linkage between the parent and child.

Although memory allocation is handled by the virtual machine it self. If you have reference to the `child` you can make it `null` yourself. Doing this will make sure that when the garbage collector is called next time, your child object will be garbage collected.

Comment: you mean by child=null will let it be erased from the memory??

Comment: Not erased immediately, but in the upcoming garbage collection cycle it will be "erased".

Answer (score 0):

According to My knowledge it will just remove the linkage, and garbage will be collected at run time.
But You can request jvm do so manually by calling **System.gc()** after removing your view.
it's not guaranteed to do anything. The JVM may just entirely ignore your request.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `System.gc()` doesn't guarantee that the garbage collector will be called. It surely does "suggest" to the garbage collector that it is a good time to collect garbage, but it doesn't guarantee that the garbage collection would be done right away.

Comment: Yeah i just read that. thanks for pointing it out i have edited my answer  :)